# Error Converting an External Table Creation Instruction to a PLSQL Procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm having some problem converting a single External table instruction into a PLSQL Procedure.
In particular, this is the External Table create instruction that works perfectly.

```
create table TMP_TBL (
  id VARCHAR2(10)
)
organization external (
  TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
  default directory DATA_DIR
  access parameters (
    RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
    fields terminated by '|'
    missing field values are null
  )
  location ('test.txt')
)
reject limit unlimited;
```

I'm trying to make out of this a PLSQL procedure that creates the table given the external data file. This is what i've done since now but i'm still having some problem when i'm calling it.

```
PROCEDURE CREATE_TMP_TBL(FILENAME VARCHAR2) IS
  BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'create table TMP_TBL (
      id VARCHAR2(10)
    )
    organization external (
      type oracle_loader
      default directory DATA_DIR
      access parameters (
        records delimited by newline
        fields terminated by ''|''
        missing field values are null
      )
      location ('''||FILENAME||''')
    )
    reject limit unlimited;';
  END CREATE_TMP_TBL;
```

Executing the procedure with the following command:

```
exec pkg_load.CREATE_TMP_TBL('test.txt');
```

It gives me this error:

```
Error report:
ORA-00911: invalid character
ORA-06512: at "PKG_LOAD", line 43
ORA-06512: at line 1
00911. 00000 -  "invalid character"
*Cause:    identifiers may not start with any ASCII character other than
           letters and numbers.  $#_ are also allowed after the first
           character.  Identifiers enclosed by doublequotes may contain
           any character other than a doublequote.  Alternative quotes
           (q'#...#') cannot use spaces, tabs, or carriage returns as
           delimiters.  For all other contexts, consult the SQL Language
           Reference Manual.
*Action:
```

line 43 is the "BEGIN" number line of the procedure CREATE_TMP_TBL.

Info:

```
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
"CORE   11.2.0.2.0  Production"
TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
```

Any suggestion to fix this problems are welcome.
Thanks in Advice,

Carlo

Comment: If all you want to potentially do is to change the file that is referenced,  You can do that with the ALTER TABLE statement - see here for all changes you can make to an external table (LOCATION attribute).  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables013.htm#i1007591

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the semicolon from the end of the statement here:

```
reject limit unlimited;';
```

ie change to

```
reject limit unlimited';
```